# HTML Form Dropdown within Radio

Tags: php, html, css, forms, radio-button

UPDATE: Sorry, when removing syntax from perl script I removed a little too much. Here's the code thus far. I am posting "student_name" to script.pl. This can either be entered in a text form or selected from the drop down box based on which you choose using a radio button. But it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
     <form method="post" action="script.pl"> 
     Type Student Name<input type="radio" name="student_name"><input type=text name="student_name" size=50> 
     <b>OR</b>
     Select Student Name<input type="radio" name="student_name">
    <select name="student_name">
     <option value="jack">Jack</option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

OLD POST----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I am trying to create a form where either a user can check the first radio button and enter a name himself or check the second button and select a value from the drop down list and pass it over. For some reason I can't get it to work properly, the value does not pass. I want whatever value is entered or selected after the radio button to be posted.

Enter Name
() _______    OR () (drop down box)

```
    <td width=30% bgcolor=#CEDBE7>Student Name</td>
    <td bgcolor=#CEDBE7 width=70%>
    <input type=radio name=student_name value=><input type=text name=student_name size=50> 

    <b>OR</b>

    <input type=radio name=student_name>
    <select>
     <option value=drop1>drop down option 1</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Not enough code to answer properly. You really should quote your elements. Plus, `value=>` that's going to buck like a mule.

Comment: You want to hide the drop down if the first radio is checked? You also need to change the name of the input field or the radios

Comment: Show your full code for your form including your PHP. This is far too unclear **and** too broad. However, this can easily be done using conditional statements. I for one can't submit an answer until I see *the whole picture* and all the parts that holds that *beautiful picture* ;-)

Comment: I have updated the code. Can you please check now

Comment: `action="script.pl"` you're running a PERL script, why? Far as I know, Perl doesn't accept POST values, *hold on...* it does but not the same way as PHP does. That makes it even harder to give you an answer. You've been given answers below, so have a talk with them about. Good luck.

Comment: even this is a perl script, I edited out all the characters and prints for a clear understanding. POST has been working for me till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I THINK you mean this

```js
window.onload=function() { // when the page has loaded
  var rads = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="student_rad"]'); // get all radios with name student_rad
  for (var i=0;i<rads.length;i++) {
    rads[i].onclick=function() { // assign onclick to each
      if (this.id=="inp") { // the one deciding input 
        document.getElementById("stud_sel").selectedIndex=0; // reset select
        document.getElementById("student_name").focus();
      }
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("stud_sel").onchange=function() { // when selecting
    document.getElementById("sel").click(); // click the rad to select it
    document.getElementById("student_name").value=this.value;
  }
  var rad = document.querySelector('input[name="student_rad"][checked]');
  if (rad == null)  {
    document.getElementById("inp").click(); // check default
  }
}
```

```html
    <td width=30% bgcolor=#CEDBE7>Student Name</td>
    <td bgcolor=#CEDBE7 width=70%>
    <input type="radio" name="student_rad" id="inp"/><input type="text" name="student_name" id="student_name" size=50 /> 

    <b>OR</b>

    <input type="radio" name="student_rad" id="sel" />
    <select id="stud_sel">
     <option value="">Please select</option>
     <option value="Frank">Frank</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Even thought I don't understand the javascript part, this works fairly well. I'm used to using only simple forms under html which works for me, but I guess more than that was needed to get this done. Thanks.

Comment: I commented some more

Answer (score 0):

Your select tag doesn't have name attribute. When form is submitted passed values are identified by element names.

Beside this your HTML looks like it was written 10 years ago. Use CSS to style elements, use table tag only for real tables, not for creating elements layout, place attribute values under the quotes.

Comment: *"Your select tag doesn't have name attribute."* - `<select>` tag? There is no select tag, not an opening one anyway ;-)